# Android Json Post shows JSONExepection (End of input at character 0 of)

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I am try to post some JSON values to my mysql table but i keep getting JSONException of (End of input at character 0 of). I have tried with postman and it is working fine but it i am getting the error when i try to run it in my andriod device here is my java code

```
            String url = "//MY url goes here//";
            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, response -> {
            try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                   String success = jsonObject.getString("message");
                    Toast.makeText(getAplicationContext, request_type + " " +success, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    progressBar1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                     if (success.equals("Request sent Successfully")) {
                        Toast.makeText(getAplicationContext.this, request_type +" Request Sent Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        progressBar1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Exception " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }, error -> Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error :: " + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()) {
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                    params.put("status", status);
                    params.put("type", type);
                    params.put("req", request);
                    return params;
                }
            };

            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

I am able to post data successfully to it using postman but it throwing the JsonException error in android so i figure it must be from my code above.Any help or advice will be greatly appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you look at the API's postman response and assert that it returns a correct json object you are expecting. E.g. 'message' key could be an object as opposed to string i.e jsonObject.getJSONObject("message")
Also,consider using google's gson library to parse the response with POJOs

for example

```
      if (callBack == null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Callback cannot be null!!!");
            }
            HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("status", status);
                    params.put("type", type);
                    params.put("req", request);

            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(_context);

            JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new JSONObject(params),
                    new com.android.volley.Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                                RespObj retObj = gson.fromJson(response.toString(), RespObj.class);
callBack.onResponse(retObj)  
                    }, new com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }) {

                @Override
                public String getBodyContentType() {
                    return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
                }

                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
                    return headers;
                }
            };
            jsonObjReq.setRetryPolicy(policy);
            jsonObjReq.setTag(tag);
            requestQueue.add(jsonObjReq);
    /*pojo*/
public class RespObj{
 private String message;
public String getMessage(){
 return message;
}
/**add this to gradle*/
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
}
```

Comment: Please how then should the code be written if it an object